# Get or create in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to have get_or_create funcionality when posting data to a model with foreign keys. None of the solutions I found had worked.

I've tried to override create method.

My Models:

```py
class Branch(models.Model):
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)

class Developer(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Commit(models.Model):
    commit_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers:

```py
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = '__all__'

class CommitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    branch = BranchSerializer()
    author = DeveloperSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Commit
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        branch_data = validated_data.pop('branch')
        author_data = validated_data.pop('author')
        branch, _ = Branch.objects.get_or_create(**branch_data)
        author, _ = Developer.objects.get_or_create(**author_data)
        return Commit.objects.create(branch=branch, author=author, **validated_data)
```

This works if none of the models instances exists in the database. However my solution fails if I try to post new commit to existing branch or using existing developer.

Django Rest framework is responding with bad request message.

I'm posting using curl and JSON.
error from curl:

```sh
{"branch":{"branch_name":["branch with this branch name already exists."]},"author":{"login":["develope
r with this login already exists."]}}
```

error from django:

```sh
Bad Request: /commits/
```

Comment: share error traceback

Comment: Done, there was not much to post tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the serializer and your post request does not even reach the `get_or_create` which you assume "not working"

Because this is what happens in your view's create:

```
 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) 

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

And `is_valid` is the part where it validates your input and returns the error.

You have multiple ways of implementing the behaviour you'd like to see.

Probably it involves changing the implementation of the view's create method. 
You would first try to obtain instance of branch and author. 
If they exist, you would use them when creating the commit serializer instead of the request data.

**Update to help resolve the problem from the comment**

if you create the branch and author in the view, you will need to change the serializer and use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead.

So your serialier will look like this:

```
class CommitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    branch = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Branch.objects.all())
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Developer.objects.all())
```

Then you can create the commit serializer in the view's create:

```
serializer = CommitSerializer(data={"author" : author_id, "branch" : branch_id})
```

And use the id from the recently created or already existing objects.

Comment: I guess, I should somehow use get_or_create method within the view's create method.

Comment: yes, something like that. but i would leave the creation to be handled by the serializer itself.  updated my answer

Comment: So, I've overwritten the view's create method: 
`branch, _= Branch.objects.get_or_create(**request.data.pop('branch'))`
`request.data.update({'branch': branch})`
But now response look like this:
`{"branch":{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got Branch."]}`

I guess, I should somehow tell the serializer to except a dict (for new branch) or instance for existing one.

Comment: @PawełRubin updated my answer to include the solution for your last problem

Comment: Thank you! It works now - I'll post my solution in an Answer so it might help someone.